# Making background fade in using Javascript

Tags: javascript, animation, jquery-animate, background-image, timed

Hello below is my JS code for a changing background image every 30 seconds. I have this example code too from research, can somebody please please please show me how to integrate the example code into my JS, so the changing image fades in as I simply have no clue where to start and feel completely lost.

My JS

```
<script>
bgArr = ['images/bg1.jpg', 'images/bg2.jpg', 'images/bg3.jpg'];
bgCur = 0;
backgroundSwitch = function()
{
if (bgCur == bgArr.length) bgCur = 0;
document.body.style.backgroundImage = 'url('+ bgArr[bgCur++]+ ')';
}
window.setInterval(backgroundSwitch, 30000); // Switch every 30 seconds.
</script>
```

Example JS that I want to integrate

```
var img = document.getElementById("fade");

var fadeLength = 5500;
var opacity = 0;
 var startTime = Date.now();

requestAnimationFrame(function me() { 
// It's faded in, stop animating!
if (opacity >= 1) {
   return;   
}

opacity = (Date.now() - startTime) / fadeLength;
img.textContent = opacity;    
img.style.opacity = opacity;        
requestAnimationFrame(me);
});
```

Also is there a way to fit the background to the browser window within the javascript without using css?

Thank you and somebody please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution here is to use CSS transitions. No JS transition needed.

```
transition: background-image 6s;
```

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/Rq5f9/)

Comment: @user3206866, its JS/Mootools, i just used the example I had to show the idea of CSS transitions. CSS is framework independent so use your code and it will work.

Comment: @user3206866 refresh your page, the fiddle online is with your js

Comment: got it working thanks segio its awesome, however the bottom of the image gets cut off by the browser window, how do i make it fit the screen vertically too?

Comment: @user3206866, you can either make a wrapper div, or use the background size, check this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Scaling_background_images